# Is there any way to get the network speed without downloading any data?

Tags: swift, macos

Is there any way to get the current **Upload and download speed without consuming any data**?
I am looking for any API from the core OS to get the current performance on mac OS.

I have an idea of developing a lively menu icon on the top of the menu bar to show the current upload and download speed. But the actual problem was if I want to know the speed, I need to download something, but in a long run it will consume a lot of data.

So, If there is any API that any OS give to check the current network speed without consuming data, it will more efficient.

Thank in advance

Comment: How could you possibly know what bandwidth is available without testing? There are way more parameters here than theoretical interface speed.

Comment: Consider: How much water will I get out of a tap without opening the valve and taking a measurement?

Comment: I knew, it, but in any OS, there is an activity monitor, that shows live network speed, I am wondering is the API is open or not?

Comment: That's just showing peak activity, not necessarily the conditions at the moment. Remember, computers can be connected to multiple networks, these networks can vary wildly in quality from one moment to the next, and nothing is certain without at least a tiny bit of testing.

Comment: macOS, as one example, does expose some kind of interface monitoring metrics as that's how tools like [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) get their data. Maybe you can find an equivalent open-source project and dig through it.

Comment: @tadman yeah, iStat Menu is doing the same, that is why I asked here. May be some kind of API is there.

Comment: Keep in mind you're not getting the "network speed" but the "network utilization", which can be two entirely different things, but otherwise that'll be an approach that can work.

Answer (score 1):

No, that’s not possible. There is no way to know the effective bandwidth without testing it.